# IBAction linked to multiple UISliders

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction

I have a view controller with 3 sliders. I only have 1 function that needs to be called every time a slider value changes - a value change in any one of the 3 sliders should cause call to that function.

How do i do that?

If I try to use outlets then I am only able to link only one UISlider.

Comment: you can select that method in IBAction for all 3 sliders. Have you tried it?

Comment: when i right click on file owner and go to received actions, I can only link it to one UISlider

Answer (score 2):

You can simply connect the `Value changed` event of all sliders to the same `IBAction`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to connect them as outlets (which is something entirely different) you will have to use an `IBOutletCollection`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> If I try to use outlets then I am only able to link one UISlider.

You need to connect the slider to a target and action, not an outlet. The target is the object that will receive a message when the slider changes, and the action is the message that will be sent to the target. An outlet, on the other hand, is a reference to some object; for example, if you connect a slider to an outlet in your view controller, the view controller will then have a reference to the slider that it can use to send messages to the slider.

Comment: This is correct. And if you want to know witch slider is, just give a tag to each one.